# why am i having error in the return F(n - 1,t) + F(n,t-1) line ?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

question :

It is mathematically proven that the following 2D recurrence relation governs the values:

```
                      F(n,t) = F(n-1,t) + F(n,t-1)
```

Now, answer the following questions:

(b) By using recursive method, implement the abovementioned relation.

(c) Test your method by using (5,5), (10, 10), and (14,14)

//main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    TwoDimension a = new TwoDimension();
    a.F(5, 5);
    a.F(10, 10);
    a.F(14, 14);
}
```

//class

```
public static class TwoDimension {

    public TwoDimension() {

    }

    public long F(int n, int t) {

            if (t == 1) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return F(n - 1, t) + F(n, t - 1);
            }


    }
}
```

this is the output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
at project2.Project2$TwoDimension.F(Project2.java:37)
```

please help meeeee, how to repair the return method ?

Comment: Do you have a base case for `n`?  That's probably what's breaking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
F(n, t - 1);
```

will evaluate the base condition of t. But

```
 F(n - 1, t)
```

there you are passing same value as t. So it will never get changed and never come to the base condition of t.
Other than that you don't have any base value for n as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your function:

public long F(int n, int t) {

```
        if (t == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return F(n - 1, t) + F(n, t - 1);
        }


}
```

For the case , `F(n - 1, t)`, `t` will always remain constant, hence `t==1` is never reached, and the recursion will not end.

You need to put in a condition for `n`, and while you're at that, you might also want to check for negative numbers :)